# does reportStateAndNotification support multiple device state reporting?

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I am trying to report the status of a couple of devices via [API](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/reference/rest/v1/devices/reportStateAndNotification)  and I am getting this error

Request payload:

```
 { 
   "requestId":"3310672920401175639",
   "agentUserId":"5d8f3dd42ce05140dc1c6a20",
   "payload":{ 
      "devices":{ 
         "states":[ 
            { 
               "5de28e041729ec0cb40ba906":{ 
                  "on":true
               }
            },
            { 
               "5df49862f53ffa4c1452a448":{ 
                  "on":false,
                  "brightness":100
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Response:

```
{ 
   "error":{ 
      "code":400,
      "message":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "states" at 'payload.devices': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
      "status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT",
      "details":[ 
         { 
            "@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
            "fieldViolations":[ 
               { 
                  "field":"payload.devices",
                  "description":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "states" at 'payload.devices': Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list."
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

can "states" hold more than one status of the device? or am I doing something wrong with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `states` value in the payload should be an object with each unique device id as a key. It should not be returned with these wrapped into an array. So your request payload should look more like this:

```
{ 
  "requestId":"3310672920401175639",
  "agentUserId":"5d8f3dd42ce05140dc1c6a20",
  "payload": { 
    "devices": { 
      "states": { 
        "5de28e041729ec0cb40ba906": { 
          "on": true
        },
        "5df49862f53ffa4c1452a448": { 
          "on": false,
          "brightness": 100
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```